# Templated projects for autohosted or provider apps don't have TokenHelper and aren't set up correctly

Tags: visual-studio, 2013, visual-studio-2012, app

When I add new project to my solution, select SharePoint 2013 App, then choose Autohosted or Provider hosted and create it, the created web project is completely empty and the projects are not set up correctly.

The web project has no TokenHelper, no pages, no jQuery, and no CSOM references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens if you create a new app in this way in a solution subfolder.

Create the project in the 'root' of the solution, and it will work - then you can move it to a folder if necessary.