# No TokenHelper.cs in Autohosted app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, mvc

I'm trying to build an Autohosted Sharepoint app based on ASP.NET MVC, following this tutorial: 
http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2012/07/building-aspnet-mvc-based-sharepoint.html

I'm stuck on "We want use the Token Helper too, so let’s copy the `TokenHelper.cs` file to our ASP.NET MVC project." step, because it's not in solution.

Is TokenHelper still used or does Sharepoint provide some other methods for authentication? Or maybe tutorial is wrong in some regard?

Also I can't seem to find `Microsoft.Identity.Extentions` dll file. This http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel/ doesn't contain it.

Comment: TokenHelper is a new concept in the App Model and is still used.  Did you start with the App for SharePoint template?

Comment: Yeah. Tried a second time, still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I found `Microsoft.Identity.Extentions` here:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/1/D/01D06854-CA0C-46F1-ADBA-EBF86010DCC6/MicrosoftIdentityExtensions-64.msi
That's needed for http://nuget.org/packages/AppForSharePointWebToolkit/ which creates TokenHelper.cs file.

I still don't know why it didn't appear automatically when creating new project for sharepoint but this download solves my problem.

Comment: The NuGet package is probably buggy or missing it. Doesn't surprise me, this package management stuff is all a bit new for Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having the same bug I found, creating the project in a solution folder?

[Templated projects for autohosted or provider apps don't have TokenHelper and aren't set up correctly](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65995/templated-projects-for-autohosted-or-provider-apps-dont-have-tokenhelper-and-ar)

Comment: Yeah, try getting it from here: http://nuget.org/packages/AppForSharePointWebToolkit/ or through download link I posted before